# How do I convert associative looping structure to codeigniter active records

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

How to convert these looping structure to codeigniter Active records....

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){     
 $result_set[] = $row;   
}


for($i=1;$i<=$nrows;$i=$i+1)
{
    $k = 0;

    if($i>0&& $i<=$count) 
    { 

        $id=$result_set[$k]['id'];
        $date=$result_set[$k]['date'];
    }
    $k = $k + 1;

}

// codeignitor code

foreach($query->result() as $row) {
                $result_set[] = $row;
}

$k = 0;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $nrows; $i = $i + 1) {

                if ($i > 0 && $i <= $count) {
                    $id = $result_set[$k]['id'];
                    $date = $result_set[$k]['date'];
                }
            }
```

Its shows the following **error**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: id
>
> Message: Undefined index: date

How to solve this issues...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your $result_set array look like? try print_r($result_set) after the while loop ends.

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5  [date] => 2016-08-17 ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your array contains an object:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 5 
    [date] => 2016-08-17 
  ) 
)
```

So, these indices should be accessed this way:

```
$id   = $result_set[$k]->id;
$date = $result_set[$k]->date;
```